# How to prevent asp.net recompiling when folder deleted from app_data?

Tags: asp.net

To Reproduce:
1. Create an asp.net website.
2. Compile and browse the default page. Keep the browser open.
3. Add a file to the app_data folder.
4. Refresh the default page. This should be fast...no recompile.
5. Delete the file from the app_data folder.
6. Refresh the default page. This should be fast...no recompile.
7. Add a folder to the app_data folder.
8. Refresh the default page. This should be fast...no recompile.
9. Delete the folder from the app_data folder.
10. Refresh the default page. This will be slow because the site recompiles.

- Is this by design? If so, what are the benefits of this behavior?
- Is there a way to disable or prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it's funky, but check out this blog from Tess, she's a ASP.NET Escalation Engineer...you will want to read her section on "Why does an application domain recycle?".

Tess' blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx

In that section she makes a reference to another blog by Todd Carter and apparently this behavior is by design to fix a bug involving preventing deleted content from being served up.

Todd's blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2006/07/17/668412.aspx

Comment: Those are great links. Still seems like a bug. The article mentions that the behavior was to prevent stale content from being served. That seems great, but if I remove a file I don't get the app domain recycle. I appreciate the links. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This by design, the app_data folder along with others are "special" asp.net folders. If you are removing files and folders to the file system you probably don't want to do it in any of the asp.net application folders. Read the link below for a detailed explaination of the folders.

http://aspalliance.com/1202_understanding_aspnet_application_folders

Comment: If this is by design, then the different behaviors for adding/deleting files, and adding folders. Only the delete folders triggers this behavior. Feels like a bug.